# Do I have to put a reverse proxy upon NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, nginx

I've been creating web-applications using `Ruby on Rails` for a while, and I'm switching to `NodeJS/ExpressJS` for my next web-application.

I'm used to put `nginx` as a reverse proxy before the `rack` stack; but for `NodeJS/ExpressJS` do I have to put a reverse-proxy in front of it ? If I have to, can you explain me why ?

Comment: You don't HAVE TO, but you can do it to improve performances. Nginx is better than the native node.js server to serve static files as said in vanadium's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, to put reverse proxy or not is your decision only. I can only say a cons for doing it.

- Reverse proxy (especially, `nginx`) can be used for balancing connections. If you have several back-end servers, you can put nginx for forwarding requests between them, and if one will be down, service will work
- Nginx can be used for serving static files, faster then node.js/RoR
- Nginx can be used for serving SSL connection and it's make your application a little lighter
- After adding reverse proxy, you can run application only on `127.0.0.1`, so there can't be executed remotely without calling nginx and logging request to it.

Hope it will help you to choose for putting `nginx` in product enviroment.

Comment: Indeed, Nginx does all that. It's better in production to use it because it makes things faster.